# How merge a list of dataframe on date to do a bar chart ? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have this list of dataframes and and would to merge them **on date** (X axis) with the others columns (Y axis) to do a bar chart:

```
[        Date  Unavailability_mec_by_Month
0 2019-10-01                      2.235304
1 2019-11-01                      1.134355
2 2019-12-01                     19.392279
3 2020-01-01                     10.063748
4 2020-02-01                      0.731397,         Date  Unavailability_transport_by_Month
0 2019-12-01                            0.674824,         Date  Unavailability_stock_by_Month
0 2019-10-01                            0.228069
1 2019-11-01                            0.145258
2 2019-12-01                            0.202965
3 2020-01-01                            1.357004
4 2020-02-01                            0.550151,         Date  Unavailability_chain_by_Month
0 2019-11-01                            0.009746
1 2019-12-01                            0.003303
2 2020-01-01                            0.016242
3 2020-02-01                            0.003328,         Date  Unavailability_prod_by_Month
0 2019-10-01                                   14.620000
1 2019-11-01                                    0.447353
2 2019-12-01                                    4.822858
3 2020-01-01                                    5.565766
4 2020-02-01                                    0.435972
```

I tried these, but it's not working:

```
from functools import reduce
#df_graph = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'Date'), list_df_graph)
#reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Date'), list_df_graph)
#merge=pd.merge(list_df_graph, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=False)
df_graph = pd.concat(list_df_graph, axis=1)
```

And the concat method, give me a result but not expected.

Thanks for your time !

**EDIT**
Expected result :

```
Date        Unavailability_mec_by_Month   Unavailability_transport_by_Month   ...
2019-10-01                     2.235304                            0.674824 
2019-11-01                     1.134355                                 NaN
2019-12-01                    19.392279                                 NaN
2020-01-01                    10.063748                                 NaN
2020-02-01                     0.731397                                 NaN
```

But currently I have a column Date for each Unavailability_..., like this:

```
Date              mec_by_Month         Date     transport_by_Month         Date  ...
2019-10-01            2.235304   2019-10-01               0.674824   2019-10-01
2019-11-01            1.134355          Nan                    NaN          NaN
2019-12-01           19.392279          Nan                    NaN          NaN
2020-01-01           10.063748          Nan                    NaN          NaN
2020-02-01            0.731397          Nan                    NaN          NaN
```

Comment: hmmm, `df_graph = pd.concat(list_df_graph, axis=1)` - `give me a result but not expected.` What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael I have edited the post with more explanations. Thanks

Comment: Can you add wrong output from `pd.concat(list_df_graph, axis=1)` ?

Comment: @jezrael It's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert column `Date` to index and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) in list comprehension for align values by `Dates` (converted to `DatetimeIndex`):

```
df_graph = pd.concat([x.set_index('Date') for x in list_df_graph], axis=1)
```

Or first column to index:

```
df_graph = pd.concat([x.set_index(x.columns[0]) for x in list_df_graph], axis=1)
```

Comment: Fantastic ! Can you explain in few lines please ?